# Как узнать версию приложения программно?

Tags: java, android

Прописала в `gradle` версию приложения, как теперь программно узнать версию данного приложения? (например, мне нужно в `Activity` узнать версию, что бы можно было отобразить в UI версию данного приложения).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Нашла решение, что бы узнать версию приложения можно использовать этот код:

```
int versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
String versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
```

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```
PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
String version = pInfo.versionName;
int verCode = pInfo.versionCode;
```

Comment: Получаю unhandled exception: android.content.pm.PackgeManager.NameNotFoundException

Comment: Я так понимаю, что этот код можно применять, когда версия приложения прописана в манифесте.

Comment: @Lucky_girl, да, я невнимательно прочитала вопрос)